# DAO Pattern - Does it povide Business Objects or plain data?

Tags: orm, domain-driven-design, dao

I am new in the world of DAO Pattern, DAL and Domain Driven Design. I am trying to understand the DAO Pattern. Every example/tutorial says that DAO abstracts the way data is persisted for several datasources. But what is the result of using a DAO object?

Does DAO retrieve pur data (columns) from the database that always corresponds to exactly one table *OR* does DAO Pattern involve some kind of Object-Relational-Mapping that resolves and loads dependencies given by foreign keys in the database and providing a *complete* Business Object in the end?

Comment: DAO is not a pattern you'll typically find in a Domain Driven Design context - I suggest you have a look at Repository

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at the `Session Façade`pattern. It is useful to encapsulate business-tier components and expose a coarse-grained service to remote clients.

As described in [this](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/SessionFacade.htm) (old) reference:

Comment: The Session facade is kind of a higher abstraction layer and interesting, but I wanted to understand the way DAOs work and if they are involved in building Business Objects with references resolved or not. I guess this is a task that is mostly done by *ORMs* or in DDD context by *Repositories* assembling aggregates.